# Understanding odata.streaming header

Tags: odata, olingo, odata-v4

I went through the OData V4 specification for understanding odata.streaming header. My doubts are:

Is this header only to determine whether the client should receive chunked responses or is it more than that?

I see a new property called Edm.Stream and this property returns a URL. When this URL is fired, the decision to stream(chunked) or no stream to be decided with the odata.streaming header?

The same doubt holds even for Media Entity. Can the $value call for a media entity be streamed always or this depends on the odata.streaming header.

To better the memory footprint, olingo has given an option to do entity level streaming for an entityset odata call. Does this streaming also depend upon odata.streaming header or can I always stream the response, since my memory of the application will be good?

On the whole it would be great if you can clarify on the odata.streaming header's purpose and its use.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here: [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/odata-discussion/qaP7juFnM7I)